# Receiving an error while executing method substring in Java

Tags: java

I have to do a String exercise where I have to enter a date like dd/mm/yyyy. Everything works fine except **if I enter a space as the input, it prints this error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 2, length 1
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3720)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1909)
    at ex5.main(ex5.java:17)
```

This is my code:

```
import cs1.*;
public class ex5
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      String data = "18/08/2011";



      //asking for the data
      System.out.printf("DATA: ");
      data = Keyboard.readString();



      //system.out
      System.out.printf("DIA: %s %n", data.substring(0, 2));
      System.out.printf("MES: %s %n", data.substring(3, 5));
      System.out.printf("ANY: %s", data.substring(6, 10)); 
   }
}
```

Comment: How long is a space, what does the method substring do? Something for you to consider

Comment: At `data = Keyboard.readString();` you may not be getting a string of proper length

Comment: a space is when you tap the space key " "

Comment: I mean I know what substring does the program just executes ok but when i put a space for the answer it returns that error

Comment: @SebastiánMoreno You cannot return a string from index `0` to index `1`, which would be a string with two characters, when the string to start with is only one character long (your entered space). Please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

Comment: @Progman so what do I do, i'm learning and i don't know what to do

Comment: @SebastiánMoreno Simple `if()` check to do your thing only when the string entered have a minimum size/length.

Comment: @Progman so what do i put in the if(), because i can't convert a string into a char

Comment: @SebastiánMoreno `if(data.length() >= 9)` or something like that, depending on what you want to do

Comment: @JoakimDanielson if i put a space nothing happens until i press enter, then it puts that error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it does nothing, just waits for an order

Answer (score 3):

### Exercise in input validation

I suggest that you test whether your input string has length 10. If it is shorter or longer, you know that it cannot have the expected format, so trying your substring calls will make no sense and may cause your program to crash as you have observed.

You need to call `data.length()`. This method will return the length of the string as an `int`, for example 10 for `18/08/2011` and 1 for a space. And you need to use an `if` statement to control that you only call `substring()` if the returned length is equal to 10. You will probably want an `else` part in which you issue a friendly message to the user about why your are not printing day, month and year. This should suffice for fixing your code.

This a very good exercise as it may help you learn something we all have to learn: To validate, to check our input in order to determine whether it fulfils the requirements for the input and whether there is good reason to believe that it is wrong. The clear and strong recommendation is that you always do this.

As you have also tried yourself, the user may enter any characters and any number of characters when your program asks for a date. Possible inputs include `18/8/2011` (one digit month and therefore too short), `18 d’agost de 2011` (too long) and any nonsense they can dream up. Make your program react as sensibly as possible in each case.

### For production code

For production code one would use a `DateTimeFormatter` from the standard library for validating the input and parsing it into a date (a `LocalDate`). Since yours is a string exercise, I am not showing you how in this answer.